# Can you explain how to write the proof of Section 1.15 Exercise 4(a) of Apostol's Calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, summation, proof-writing, partitions-for-integration

I am attempting to self-study Calculus from Apostol's book, but I have gotten stuck on the proof for Exercise 4(a).

There are indeed other solutions, such as the below two links, but they don't explain the steps very well.

http://www.stumblingrobot.com/2015/07/18/compute-some-integrals-of-step-functions/
https://iiserbbookstore.files.wordpress.com/2016/01/tom-apostol-v1-solutions.pdf

Here is the required information.

> Definition of the Integral of Step Functions $$\int_a^bs(x)dx = \sum_{k=1}^ns_k \cdot (x_k - x_{k-1})$$
>   Where $s_k$ is the value of $s(x)$ along the $k$-th open subinterval of a partition $P$ of $[a, b].$

Here is the actual question:

> If $n \in \mathbb Z^+$, prove that $\int_0^n[t]dt = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ where $[t]$ denotes the greatest integer $\le t$.

I also don't completely understand the relationship between $n$ from the Definition of the Integral of Step Functions, and $b$, the upper limit of integration.

Any aid you could provide would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know that $\sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac {n(n+1)}2$?

Comment: @fleablood Yes, I already proved that by induction in an earlier exercise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, a step function is one where there exists $a =x_{0} < x_1 < .... < x_n = b$ and if $x_{k-1} < x < x_{k}$ then $f(x) = s_k$ for some constant.  (and $f(x_k) = $ either $s_{k}$ or $s_{k-1}$ but those values don't affect the integral).

$[t]$ is precisely such a step function.  Where $a=0= x_0; b= n=x_n$ and on the interval $t\in (x_{k-1}, x_k) = (k-1, k)$ then $[t]  = k-1 = s_k$.  And each $x_{k} - x_{k-1} = 1$.

So by that definition and those intervals and those indexes:

$\int_{0}^n [t]dt = \sum_{k=1}^n s_k*(x_k - x_{k-1}) =\sum_{k=1}^n (k-1)*1 = \sum_{k=1}^n (k-1)$.

And that's it.

Proving that $\sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac {n(n+1)}2$ is a well known trick and is beside the point of what this exercise is supposed to teach you.  You may take that as a given as it has nothing to do with calculus.

So $\sum_{k=1}^{n} (k-1) = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} j = \frac {(n-1)n}2$

Alternatively $\sum_{k=1}^{n} (k - 1)= \sum_{k=1}^n k - \sum_{k=1}^n 1 = \frac {n(n+1)}2 - n = \frac {n(n-1)}2$.

Comment: Thank you. The question wants the proof to be for $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ though.

Comment: Thank you. How do you know your sentence "$[t]$ precisely such a step function where..."?

Comment: Because .... it is?????

Comment: $[t]$ is the function $f(t) = n$ if $n \le t < n+1$... that's ... a step function.  That's precisely what a step function is.

Comment: That you. I know that. How do you know it equals $k-1$? Is that the same $k$ as the one on the sigma?

Comment: Because we set it up to be.... indexes can be whatever we want them to be.  Your text choose that $a = x_0$ and $b= x_n$ and that the $k-th$ interval is $(x_{k-1}, x_k)$ and that $f(x)=s_k$ if $x \in (x_{k-1}, x_k)$.  Translating that.  The $k-th$ interval is $(k-1, k)$.  ... Look, we are starting at $0$ and ending at $n$, so the intervals we are using are $[0,1), [1,2),....., [n-1, n)$.

Comment: Maybe it'd be easier not to try to hammer the values into the variable.  $\int_0^n [t]dt = \int_0^1 [t]dt +  \int_1^2 [t]dt+  \int_2^3 [t]dt +... +  \int_{n-1}^n [d]dt=  \int_0^1 0dt +  \int_1^2 1dt+  \int_2^3 2dt +... +  \int_{n-1}^n (n-1)dt = 0(1-0) + 1(2-1) + 2(3-1) + ...... + (n-1)(n - (n-1)) = 0 + 1 + 2+ .... + n-1$

Comment: I picked those variables to *force* them into the form.

Comment: Frankly, If I wrote that book, I wouldn't use $s_k$ to refer to the output of the interval $(x_{k-1}, x_k)$.  I'd use the variable $s_j$ to refer to the output of the interval $(x_j, x_{j+1})$ so I'd write the formula as $\int_a^b s(x) dx = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} s_j(x_{j+1}- x_j)$.  They both have the exact same results.  There are advantages and disadvantages to each, I guess.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments and the answer edit. It all makes sense now. I've mentioned this before on this site, but I'm 16 years old and attempting to use Apostol's book (rather than a high school book) because of it's mathematical rigor. I'm taking this Summer to self-study Calculus because I think math is beautiful, elegant, and poetic. 

Do you have any advice for how to approach proofs in general? I find that with enough work, I can understand a proof, but I'm not great at writing them on my own, from scratch.

Thank you for all of your help.

Answer (score 2):

By definition\begin{align}\int_0^n\lfloor t\rfloor\,\mathrm dt&=0\times(1-0)+1\times(2-1)+\cdots+(n-1)\times\bigl(n-(n-1)\bigr)\\&=1+2+\cdots+(n-1)\\&=\frac{n(n-1)}2.\end{align}

Comment: Thank you. The question wants the proof to be for $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ though.

Comment: @JamieCorkhill I've edited my answer. I hope that everything is clear now.